# Mongoose assign findOne() result to variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function:

```
function RetrieveCountryCode(countryName, callback) {
  Country.find({ name: countryName }, function(err, country) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      callback(null, country.code);
    }
  });
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
//find a country code of a given country by user
var userCountryCode = null;
RetrieveCountryCode(country, function(err, countryCode) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  userCountryCode = countryCode;
});
console.log("COUNTRY CODE");
console.log(userCountryCode);
```

*Parameter 'country' given to a function is from html form, it's passed correctly, I checked it.

And I still get the same response in console: COUNTRY CODE **null**. What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: RetrieveCountryCode is an asynchronous function, so javascript calls RetrieveCountryCode, but does not wait it and continues to execute code, so you get null in userCountryCode. You need to log and use it inside the RetrieveCountryCode call.

Comment: But I would like to use the countryCode variable later in my code - pass it as a parameter to model creating. How am I supposed to achieve that? Should I lock the code until I get this value from DB = until countryCode is not null anymore? How to do it?

Comment: You can't do that. Please have a look at these: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/async-programming-with-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-980e3f144185

Comment: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff

Comment: Before I read those links : so what can I do with a result of FindOne if it can not be assigned to?

Comment: You need to put your logic inside the RetrieveCountryCode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202024/discussion-between-kamil-turowski-and-suleymansah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Suleyman said in the comments, this is due to node's async nature. The flow of the code is not like what you expect. There are a lot of tutorial on the internet regarding node's async nature, and I suggest you understand them and experiment with them since it's not very intuitive at first.

Due to this, the `console.log(userCountyCode)` was executed before `RetrieveCountryCode()` can finish its work.

The solution is to put the `console.log(userCountyCode)` *inside* the callback.

For example, if my collection contains:

```
> db.countries.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dc4fcee86c118c901a7de35"), "name" : "Australia", "code" : "61", "__v" : 0 }
```

Using a modified version of the code you have:

```
var userCountryCode = null;
var country = 'Australia';

mongoose.connect(url, opts)

function RetrieveCountryCode(countryName, callback) {
  Country.findOne({ name: countryName }, function(err, country) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      callback(null, country.code);
    }
  });
}

RetrieveCountryCode(country, function(err, countryCode) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  userCountryCode = countryCode;
  console.log("COUNTRY CODE");
  console.log(userCountryCode);
});
console.log('xxx');
```

Note that I didn't change the definition of the `RetrieveCountryCode` function at all. I just changed how it's called and moved the `console.log` *inside* the callback. I put `console.log('xxx')` in its place instead.

Running this code outputs:

```
xxx
COUNTRY CODE
61
```

Note that `xxx` was printed **before** the country code since it was executed before the callback prints the result of the query.

In conclusion, your code always prints `null` because:

1. You print the variable content before it was filled by the query.
2. You didn't print the variable content inside the callback.

**Note**: I changed the `find()` in your code to `findOne()`. I believe the `find()` is a typo on your part.

Comment: After joining both of the answers together (Yours and the one above) I just moved the logic inside (in the app, it's not just a console log, but a whole user creation), and had to nest two findOne() functions. In fact, find() was a typo, but not only here, but also in my code... Thank You!